# Ruby date and time conversion from one format to other

Tags: ruby, time, format

I have to convert time from this format to this
eg : 02/16/2015:19:16:07 #=> 20150216191607
I have written code like this :

```
def convert_date(old_date)
    new_date = old_date[6..9] + old_date[0..1]+old_date[3..4]+old_date[11..12]+old_date[14..15] + old_date[17..18]
    return new_date
end
```

But I have heard of Time and Date class in ruby which provide the parse and strftime method to do this elegantly. I tried it out and can get the Date and Time formatted individually but not together in the format I want. Can somebody point out the usage for my format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'date'

def convert_date(old_date)
  DateTime.strptime(old_date, '%m/%d/%Y:%H:%M:%S').strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
end

convert_date('02/16/2015:19:16:07')   
  #-> 20150216191607
```

Comment: Thanks Cary! was not aware of DateTime

Comment: Note `DateTime.superclass #=> Date`. You can instead write `require 'time'`; Time.strptime....`.